# drupal override node reference autocomplete

Tags: drupal, autocomplete, overriding

I have a field called **"fruit_type"** which is a node reference to a **"fruit"** content type and an auto-complete field.

By default drupal provides title of node and nodeId in auto-complete field like:

```
mango [nid:9]
```

My requirement is to show the field from **"fruit"** content type called **"fruit_species"**. So it should look something like this:

```
mango [spec:mangifera indica]
```

But the further functionality of node reference should remain the same, i.e. on content page I should be able to get the values entered in this field as a reference to a node of type **"fruit"** and redirect me to the content page of this fruit.

Is it possible to achieve? If yes how can I achieve this?

**Edit:** FYI: I am using a Drupal 6

Comment: Yes it's possible, you'll need to implement your own autocomplete/machine-name widget and then set your field to use that widget. Check out the `field_example` module in [Examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) for more details

Comment: I am working in drupal 6. And I do not find field_example module in examples.

Comment: It's similar for Drupal 6 but you'll have to go digging through the CCK module to find out how it implements widgets and use that as a base example. You'll have to have the `[nid]` in there somewhere though, how else do you expect Drupal to perform a link to the referenced node?

Comment: It ok for it to have nid but atleast along with it It should display spec also like: mango [spec: mangifera indica] [nid:9]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use [Nodereference Explorer](http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_explorer) as it's what I use when I need more than what autocompelte offers. It doesn't do what you want but maybe is what you need.

Other than that, you could implement your own autocomplete module. Using one of the many widgets available online.

For the results, you'll need to set up a hook_menu to build your results (and link them to the widget) and then using hook_form to process them before creating the node reference.

Comment: Hi Miguel. Thank you for your response. I solved this using Super Node Reference. Though I have to hack it to make it work for my needs. I did the same thing you mentioned about custom autocomplete in Super Node Reference.